# How to change the coordinate value of point feature in gdb using GDAL？

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase

After installing the FileGDB API plugin, I tried to modify the coordinate values of the vector point features in GDB, but the modified results **could not be saved** after the modification.In other words,the coordinate values of the vector point can't be modified. Code show as below:

```
    void WriteGDB(const char* gdbpath)
{
    GDALAllRegister();
    CPLSetConfigOption("GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8", "NO");  
    CPLSetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "");
    GDALDriver* driver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("FileGDB");

    if (driver != NULL)
    {
        cout << "No null" << endl;
        GDALDataset* ds ;
        ds=(GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx(gdbpath, GDAL_OF_VECTOR & GDAL_OF_UPDATE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        cout << ds->GetLayerCount() << endl;
        
        OGRLayer* layer = ds->GetLayerByName("DZ_Project");
        OGRFeature* poFeature = NULL;
        
        while ((poFeature = layer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL)
        {
            OGRGeometry* poGeometry = poFeature->GetGeometryRef();
            // Modify Point
            if (poGeometry != NULL && wkbFlatten(poGeometry->getGeometryType()) == wkbPoint)
            {
                OGRPoint* point = (OGRPoint*)poGeometry;
                double point_x = point->getX();
                double point_y = point->getY();
                cout.precision(10);
                cout << "X:" << point_x << "  " << "Y:" << point_y << endl;

                point->setX(112.9);
                point->setY(28.9);
                poFeature->SetGeometry(point);
                layer->SetFeature(poFeature);
            }
        }
        OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(poFeature);
        GDALClose(ds);
    }
}
```

I output the OGRErr, and I found the code "poFeature->SetGeometry(point)" is OGRERR_NONE, the code "layer->SetFeature(poFeature)" is Unsupported operation.So how to solve this problem.

Comment: "could not be saved"means the coordinate values of the vector point can't be modified, and I can't find the real reason.

Comment: When i run the code,thre is no error occurs. But i output the OGRErr, and I found the code "poFeature->SetGeometry(point)" is right, the code "layer->SetFeature(poFeature)" is Unsupported operation. So,Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to edit your original question and update it to include all this new information.  You should be checking for OGR_ERRNONE (or otherwise) as the return code for for those operations.

Comment: Maybe the Python tests of the GDAL project could help https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_fgdb.py even a test for updating a geometry may be missing.